# Should we allow "How do I prove something", "How can I refute this argument" type of questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, close-reasons

Examples:

- [How do I prove casteism is not an inherent part of Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26801/2995)
- [Feminist's claim that the Vedas, Ramayana and Mahabharata were written by male writers](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8981/2995) 
  (*my own question from early days on the site*)

The drawback of framing your questions this way is that you only want to only hear the *truth* that *you* want to hear. These are not knowledge or truth questions anymore.

The above questions could be better phrased as:

- Is casteism an inherent part of Hinduism?
- Are feminists' claim that the Vedas, Ramayana and Mahabharata were written by male writers justified?

...which allows for both viewpoints (yes & no) to be posted as answers.

Should we close *How do I prove something* type of questions as opinion-based?

Comment: Yeah, it's better to ask whether something is true than what arguments can be made against something.  It can make sense to ask about arguments for something or arguments against something, but only if you're asking about a particular person or group's arguments.  Like "What are Advaitins' arguments for the world being Maya?" or "What is the Sri Vaishnava argument for Sharanagati being an independent means to Moksha?"

Comment: Hypothetically if such posts are disallowed, even then it won't be easy for a moderator to close it. Because every such Qn is different from each other & very subjective. It will be left to community to decide if it's opinion based or not.

Comment: Needn't be closed, just rephrased. Close only when OP wants to retain the original wording. @iammilind

Comment: We can refute the claims and answer too. For e.g for the 1st one we can say " Casteism is definitely part of Hinduism" and then we will support our points with the sources. @sv. So even if they ask in this manner it's not much of a problem.

Comment: Is "How to prove casteism is inherent to Hinduism?" equally valid on this site and not a duplicate of the other? So for every "How to prove xyz" there should be its counterpart "How to disprove xyz"...? Asking "Is xyz true or justified" makes more sense to me @Rickross

Comment: Yes then one is a duplicate of the other..  "makes more sense to me" Ok but I think it's just the case of different users asking the same thing in different ways.. @sv.

Comment: Answers to both will be different, hence not dup. IMO. When my motive is to prove something, why will I accept an answer which disproves the same thing? @Rickross

Comment: Well not sure about you but if i'm satisfied with the refutation of my belief then i may very well accept that answer :D @sv.. also i'm not sure how they judge duplicates here.. some say it's based on questions others say no based on answers..

Comment: @Rickross Why don't you try answering "How do I prove casteism is not an inherent part of Hinduism?" in the negative and see what OP does :) There's already an answer like that by moonstar but it's missing references. "some say it's based on questions others say no based on answers" - I used to think it's based on answers but have changed my view over time. It's most definitely based on the question. I have edited several questions explaining how they're not dup. so they can be reopened.

Comment: @sv. See a [somewhat similar nature Q](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22289/what-scriptural-verse-proves-or-disproves-that-water-is-as-pure-as-the-contain) and this time it's from me.